# How to count the average count(*) in sql?

Tags: mysql

I have a `Photos` table that contains `photo_id` and `user_id`, here is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE photos
(
    ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    image_url VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
);
```

I want to use the `COUNT(*)` function to calculate the average of each user who has posted how many photos, but I don't know to calculate it, here is the error. Could you please help me?

Mysql:

```
-> select user_id, count(*) AS total,AVG(count(*))
-> from photos
-> group by user_id;
```

> ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: Can you please explain login behind calculating the average ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL 8+, then the following query would be valid:

```sql
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS total, AVG(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS total_avg
FROM photos
GROUP BY user_id;
```

The alias `total_avg` would be the average of total counts, across all users in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which version of SQL you're using. Postgres doesn't allow nested function calls, ie AVG(COUNT(*)), in which case you would have to make a subquery.

```
SELECT user_id, AVG(count) AS total 
FROM (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) 
      FROM photos 
      GROUP BY user_id) AS sub
GROUP BY user_id;
```